# Emulate Lightroom list order with PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I would like to emulate the same way that Lightroom orders a list, using PHP. I have tried a number of different methods, but still can't copy the order exactly. Here are my examples:

```
Lightroom ordered (the way I want to order my list):
abcd fgh
abcd0
abcd1
abcd2
abcd3
abcd10
abcd11
abcd22
abcdefgh
abcd'fgh
abcd-fgh


My tests:

PHP: sort($line_list, SORT_NATURAL); natcasesort($line_list);
abcd'fgh
abcd-fgh
abcd0
abcd1
abcd2
abcd3
abcd10
abcd11
abcd22
abcdefgh
abcd fgh

PHP: asort($line_list);
abcd fgh
abcd'fgh
abcd-fgh
abcd0
abcd1
abcd10
abcd11
abcd2
abcd22
abcd3
abcdefgh

PHP: sort($line_list, SORT_FLAG_CASE);
abcd fgh
abcd'fgh
abcd-fgh
abcd0
abcd1
abcd10
abcd11
abcd2
abcd22
abcd3
abcdefgh

PHP: sort($line_list, SORT_STRING);
abcd fgh
abcd'fgh
abcd-fgh
abcd0
abcd1
abcd10
abcd11
abcd2
abcd22
abcd3
abcdefgh

PHP: sort($line_list, SORT_NUMERIC);
abcd3
abcdefgh
abcd'fgh
abcd-fgh
abcd22
abcd2
abcd0
abcd1
abcd10
abcd11
abcd fgh
```

Is there a way to copy the Lightroom ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// Comparison function
function mySortingFunction($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);
print_r($array);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'mySortingFunction');
print_r($array);
?>
```

using this example, you will just have to create your own sorting function.

Comment: I realise that I *can* create my own sorting function. What I don't understand is *how* to create a function that matches my desired order.

Comment: give a value to all your characters (eg, a = 1, b= 2, . = 27) and break all the word in characters and test the value of each chars (eg, abc and afd, a==a, b<f , then abc come first). it will be very long to do but php does exactly that  but uses ascii values. good luck